# Representing different borders in tmap legend

Tags: r, legend, tmap

my map looks similar to this one:

```
# import shapefile
shape_data <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
shape_data <- st_read(shape_data) 
sample_data <- filter(shape_data, CNTY_ID >2100)
shape_area <- st_union(shape_data) 
#map data
tm_shape(shape_data) + tm_borders(alpha = 0.4,lwd = 0.1, col = "blue") +
tm_fill(col = "BIR79", style = "equal") +
tm_shape(sample_data)  + tm_borders(col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 4) +
tm_shape(shape_area) + tm_borders(col = "black", lwd = 2)
```

the polygons in the map are distinguished by three types of boundaries, with different colours, size and, in one case, by dashes. Now, I would like to find a way to represent these 3 boundaries in a legend, either in addition to the data legend or even separate. So I would like to have the representation of the type of boundaries (red dashed, black and blue with their different size, and next to them add a text explaining what they represent, i.e. districts, boundaries of the study area and so on.

Do you have any idea how to do this with tmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation using `tm_add_legend` might look something like this, although it's hard to display the dotted red line segment with `lwd = 3` in the legend from my point of view.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

# import shapefile
shape_data <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")
shape_data <- st_read(shape_data) 
sample_data <- filter(shape_data, CNTY_ID > 2100)
shape_area <- st_union(shape_data) 

# map data
tm_shape(shape_data) + 
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.4, lwd = 0.1, col = "blue") +
  tm_fill(col = "BIR79", style = "equal") +
  tm_shape(sample_data) + 
  tm_borders(col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 4) +
  tm_shape(shape_area) + 
  tm_borders(col = "black", lwd = 2) +
  tm_add_legend(type = "line", 
                col = c("blue", "red", "black"),
                lwd = c(0.1, 3, 2),
                lty = c(1, 4, 1),
                labels = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
```

Feel free to adjust attributes to your own needs.

Comment: Hi @dimfalk, your solution is good, thanks! What if I want to change the legend position of the borders and move it on the right so that I'll have two legends, one on the left and one on the right

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a possibility to split the tmap legend in two blocks and place them separately, but you can control placement in general via `+ tm_layout(legend.position = c("left", "top"))`. Guess `ggplot2` would give you more control, but maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Update: Native splitting does not seem to be possible, c.f. [r-tmap/tmap#476](https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/476), but a workaround is mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the link you sent me, that's a feasible way to work around the problem